# history table: 1 vs 2 foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a "controller_variables" table where I save current values of some sensors:

- **id**: the id of the record
- **controller_id (FK)**: the id of the controller that provides the data
- **variable_id (FK)**: the variable_id
- **value**: the current variable value
- **created_at**: creation date
- **updated_at**: updated date

I also have "history_controller_variables" table where I save "snapshots" of the "controller_variables" table:

- **id**: the id of the record
- **controller_variable_id (FK)**: the id of the controller_variables record
- **value**: the "historified" read value
- **created_at**: creation date of the history value

I found myself a few times wondering why I coupled the "history_controller_variables" table to the "controller_variables" table.

If I created the history table as an exact clone of the original table I could:

- keep my history in case the referenced "controller_variables" record is deleted.
- get history records by directly querying records of a certain controller_id/variable_id.

I can't think of a reason why not to do this change. Are there obvious reasons not to proceed with this change?

Comment: I wouldn't do an exact clone.  I'd have a datetimeof the history record.  I would have a trigger on the controller_variables to insert new values into the history table.  I would also keep a LastModifiedBy so I know who made the change if possible incase there are questions.  The trigger ensures anything writing to the table is logged; incase some coding flaw forgets to.

Comment: I forgot to add created_at and updated_at, it didn't make much sense before

Comment: Do you really need both?  you could also have an action code to handle Insert/Update/Delete and a single timestamp/datetime.

Comment: it's the Rails implementation to keep track of creation and modification timestamps. I rather keep it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a fairly big tradeoff here.  I don't know which is better, but I can tell you what the advantages of each are.

If your variables for your controllers will not change, then you want to go with one foreign key.  This makes it easier to ensure correctness, that the history record represents a valid value for a given controller.  If, on the other hand these change and you delete records from the controller variable table, you run into a problem here that has no easy solution.  So in that case, you are better off using two.

Ultimately we never know the future and for that reason I would tend to accept some risk of odd data in exchange for ensuring that operational and historical data is subject to different concerns and that changing the data doesn't mess with history.

Comment: "Ultimately we never know the future and for that reason I would tend to accept some risk of odd data in exchange for ensuring that operational and historical data is subject to different concerns and that changing the data doesn't mess with history." That means you would go with 2?

Comment: Yes, I would probably go with two.  But that is not necessarily a firm recommendation.  If these sensors are not field reprogrammable or you cannot add/remove variables then that may not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good change to do. Have the history table be a clone of the original table, but add a timestamp column to the history table. Any time a variable value changes, create a new record in the history table with the new value, and have the timestamp indicate when the variable was changed to that value. If applicable in your application, you can also include a column in your history table that indicates who (or what) modified the variable to be the new value.

Comment: You only told me it was good for me to do that change. You didn't give any explanation though

Comment: Good point. Sorry about that - I just meant that the reasons you gave are good: Decoupling and also avoiding foreign key issues.